# Audio on scroll in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, audio, scroll

I want to enable audio in a selected area of the page. If the user scrolls out this element, audio will stop.
I found this solution but the problem is that pixels values are different in order the resolution of the window, monitor, kind of browser etc.

```
var playing = false;
var audioElm = $('#soundTour').get(0);
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var pageScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(!playing && pageScroll > 500 && pageScroll < 3000){
    audioElm.play();
    playing = true;
  }else if(pageScroll > 3000 || pageScroll < 500){
    audioElm.pause();
    playing = false;
  }
});
```

For that I'd like to find a **solution in a DIV.**
My one page is like this:
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html#firstPage
and I want that the background sound, for example, will autoplay during the first and second page, and will stop when the user join the third page.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code below sound starts playing when 30% of the third block is visible.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio src="/sound.wav"></audio>
    <div style="height: 100%; background: #ff5555">first page</div>
    <div style="height: 100%; background: #55ff55">second page</div>
    <div id="d3" style="height: 100%; background: #5555ff">third page</div>
    <script>
     const el = document.querySelector("audio");
     let playing = false;
     window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
       const scroll = e.target.body.scrollTop;
       const rect = document.getElementById("d3").getBoundingClientRect();
       const top = rect.top;
       if (!playing && top > rect.height / 3) {
         el.play();
         playing = true;
       } else if (top < rect.height / 3) {
         el.pause();
         playing = false;
       }
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update after comments:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="d1" style="height: 100%; background: #ff5555">first page</div>
    <div id="d2" style="height: 100%; background: #55ff55">second page</div>
    <div id="d3" style="height: 100%; background: #5555ff">third page</div>
    <script>
     const soundfiles = ["sound.wav", "sound2.wav", "sound.wav"];
     const divIds = ["d1", "d2", "d3"];
     const els = soundfiles.map((filename, index) => {
       const el = document.createElement("audio");
       el.src = "/" + filename;
       document.body.appendChild(el);
       return el;
     })
     const playing = new Array(divIds.length).fill(false);
     window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
       const scroll = e.target.body.scrollTop;
       const rects = divIds.map(id => document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect());
       const tops = rects.map(rect => rect.top);
       tops.forEach((top, ind) => {
         if (!playing[ind] && top <= rects[ind].height * 2 / 3 && top > - rects[ind].height * 1 / 3) {
           els[ind].play();
           playing[ind] = true;
         } else if (playing[ind] && (top > rects[ind].height * 2 / 3 || top < -rects[ind].height * 1 / 3)) {
           els[ind].pause();
           playing[ind] = false;
         }
       });
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very interesting @Alexander ! Thank you very much. The sound start at beginning of my page and stop in the point where I put id=d3. I my case I want to add more than one sound, after the first, and my question is how can I modify your script to decide the second start point, the third start point etc.

Comment: thank you for your update, but maybe I'm doing something wrong in the path? the mp3s are in the audio folder

const soundfiles = ["intro.mp3", "window.mp3", "human_voices.mp3"];
     const divIds = ["d1", "d2", "d3"];
     const els = soundfiles.map((filename, index) => {
       const el = document.createElement("audio");
       el.src = "audio/" + filename;
       document.body.appendChild(el);
       return el;

Comment: It works!! thank you @Alexander Smirnov! I renamed my folder in "songs" and now it works! thank you very much!!

Comment: uhm ... today the second solution stopped to works :-( the first one still works. I have now the same problem, I don't know how to autoplay the second audio, the third audio in following selected div. what's wrong @Alexander?

Comment: @EarlJ.Hickey, i've updated second algorithm a little bit. Take a look.

Comment: great @Alexander! thank you! now it works! what does it refer 2 / 3 and 1 / 3? where I have to add the audio fade out in your script ? I did some tests but without lucky.

Comment: 2/3 of the height should be visible in order to play sound. When more than 1/3 of height of visible block goes beyond the screen music stopes. I don't understand what you mean by 'fade out' of audio, i can do only pause without fading. I'm not sure if it is possible at all.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for your help @Alexander. So I need to play with height value because the sound stops too soon before the last slide is completely visible. That's why I asked about the fade out, to have some seconds more of sound before it stop.

Comment: editing 2/3 and 1/3 in fact is possible to see the effect on the slide, thank you! Is possible to have audio loop? I'd like the sound restart if you stay on the slide when you don't  scroll the page.

Comment: Yes, its possible. Add ```el.loop = true;``` after ```el.src = "/" + filename;``` where audio elements are created.

Comment: thank you very much @Alexander. It works like a charm!